# Converting API Response into Dataframe for SQL Import

Tags: python, json, dataframe, api, rest

I have a REST API code as follows:

```
api_response = req.post('APIUrl', params=api_param,headers=api_header, json=api_body)
```

The json looks like

```
[
  {
    "productStatusMessage": "ACOPS ARE AVAILABLE FOR THIS CUSTOMER AND SKU",
    "ingramPartNumber": "123512",
    "vendorPartNumber": "LS1016A-CISCO",
    "customerPartNumber": "A5-8963TEST",
    "upc": "0718908728116",
    "partNumberType": "T",
    "vendorNumber": "1234",
    "vendorName": "INTERNAL",
    "description": "6FT PARALLEL PRINTER DB25M TO  SVCS CENT36M PRO SERIES 28AWG ROHS",
    "productClass": "P",
    "uom": "EA",
    "acceptBackOrder": true,
    "productAuthorized": true,
    "returnableProduct": true,
    "endUserInfoRequired": true,
    "availability": {
      "available": true,
      "totalAvailability": 240479,
      "availabilityByWarehouse": [
        {
          "location": "Fort Worth, TX",
          "warehouseId": "20",
          "quantityAvailable": 105415
        },
        {
          "location": "Carol Stream, IL",
          "warehouseId": "40",
          "quantityAvailable": 1049
        }
      ],
      "pricing": {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "retailPrice": 10,
        "mapPrice": 540.25,
        "customerPrice": 5.43
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I import it into a dataframe and write to a text file using:

```
json_df = pd.read_json(api_response.text, orient='records')
with open (txt_file,'w') as me:
        me.write(json_df.to_string(header=True, index = True))
```

The file looks like the following:

```
  PartNumber vendorPartNumber           upc partNumberType vendorNumber vendorName                                                description productClass uom  acceptBackOrder  productAuthorized  returnableProduct  endUserInfoRequired                                                                                                                                                                          availability                                                                                    pricing
0           123512          LS1016A-CISCO  0718908728116              T         1234     6FT PARALLEL PRINTER DB25M TO  SVCS CENT36M PRO SERIES 28AWG ROHS            P  EA             True               True               True                False   {'available': False, 'totalAvailability': 28374, 'availabilityByWarehouse': [{'location': 'Anywhere, IL', 'warehouseId': '15', 'quantityAvailable': 890, 'quantityBackordered': 54},{'location': 'BFE, TX', 'warehouseId': '67', 'quantityAvailable': 3456, 'quantityBackordered': 122}]}  {'currencyCode': 'USD', 'retailPrice': 69.0, 'mapPrice': 69.0, 'customerPrice': 39.59}
```

This issue I'm having is getting the nested list 'availabilityByWarehouse' to be parsed out so that I have the following dataframe for importing into a SQL table.

```
PartNumber vendorPartNumber           upc partNumberType vendorNumber vendorName                                                description productClass uom  acceptBackOrder  productAuthorized  returnableProduct  endUserInfoRequired                                                                                                                                                                          availabilityByWarehouse                                                                                    pricing
0           123512          LS1016A-CISCO  0718908728116              T         1234     6FT PARALLEL PRINTER DB25M TO  SVCS CENT36M PRO SERIES 28AWG ROHS            P  EA             True               True               True                False   {'location': 'Anywhere, IL', 'warehouseId': '15', 'quantityAvailable': 890, 'quantityBackordered': 54}}  {'currencyCode': 'USD', 'retailPrice': 69.0, 'mapPrice': 69.0, 'customerPrice': 39.59}               NaN                      NaN           NaN
1           123512          LS1016A-CISCO  0718908728116              T         1234     6FT PARALLEL PRINTER DB25M TO  SVCS CENT36M PRO SERIES 28AWG ROHS            P  EA             True               True               True                False   {'location': 'BFE, TX', 'warehouseId': '67', 'quantityAvailable': 3456, 'quantityBackordered': 122}  {'currencyCode': 'USD', 'retailPrice': 69.0, 'mapPrice': 69.0, 'customerPrice': 39.59}
```

Do I need to create another dataframe for the availability and then merge or is there a way to perform what I need inplace with the current dataframe?  I'm fairly new with Python programming so if I'm missing something fundamental to Python, please call me out.

Edit:
Added the Python code that creates the dataframe and the output of the dataframe.  I had pipe-delimited my first post for readability.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The output of `pd.read_json(response.text)` doesn't fit to the given example json data.

Comment: edit your question and add this code to it, not as comment. and in your question is still data that doesn't fit to the given example. Please show some effort and make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted some elements for demonstration purpose, didn't change how data us structured. What you actually want is a flattened dataframe of a nested dictionary with 2 levels (if I understand correctly).

So here is the data I used:

```json
data2 = """[
    {
        "PartNumber": "123512",
        "vendorNumber": "1234",
        "returnableProduct": true,
        "availability": {
            "available": true,
            "totalAvailability": 240479,
            "availabilityByWarehouse": [
                {
                    "location": "Anywhere, IL",
                    "warehouseId": "15"
                },
                {
                    "location": "BFE, TX",
                    "warehouseId": "67"
                }
            ],
            "pricing": {
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "retailPrice": 69
            }
        }
    }
]
"""
```

data2 is a string in json format, that should be the equivalent to `response.text` in your code. I commented it out like you would run the code.

```py
# tmp = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(response.text))
tmp = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data2))

out = (
    pd.concat(
        {
            i: pd.DataFrame(x) for i, x in tmp.pop("availability.availabilityByWarehouse").items()
        }
    )
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    .join(tmp)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
       location warehouseId PartNumber vendorNumber  returnableProduct  availability.available  availability.totalAvailability availability.pricing.currencyCode  availability.pricing.retailPrice
0  Anywhere, IL          15     123512         1234               True                    True                          240479                               USD                                69
1       BFE, TX          67     123512         1234               True                    True                          240479                               USD                                69
```

Comment: This answers my question.  Thanks!

Comment: I keep running into "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list" error so I utilized your code as is and get the same error.  Is there an issue with the type of object the JSON is?

Comment: you can check [here](https://jsonlint.com/) if you have valid json data. maybe something is wrong there.

Comment: @Ryan_The_Noob I think the problem is, `json.loads` expects to get a string as input. You don't have a string, instead a list. Try to use `json.load`

Comment: json.load gives me the error 
'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: can you add the data (list) you try to pass to json load or loads to your question? Or is it already the json we see at the beginning

Comment: It is the json at the beginning.  I also found that when I enter your json example data I get the same errors.  I must be missing something fundamental in the json data.

Comment: just tried it again. If I just take my data and run my code, it works on my side.... Maybe restart everything and try again. one more possibility is. Your `response.text` is just a json wrapped in a list. did you try: `tmp = pd.json_normalize(json.load(api_response[0]))`. like that you pick the 1. list element which is a json object.

Comment: I will try that.  Also, this is the API documentation from the site https://developer.ingrammicro.com/reseller/api-documentation#operation/post-priceandavailability

Comment: Your last comment got me in the correct direction.  Thank you for your assistance on this.

Comment: glad you figured it out. I was officially out of ideas after that :D Accept/vote my answer if you are happy with it :)

Comment: I tried to vote, but I'm too new and it won't let me.  Says I need a 15 reputation to cast a vote.

Comment: ah I see. That's true, then nervermind :). Does that also apply for accepting ? did you try to press the green check?